Docker COPY syntax
What does this COPY command do:
COPY dir:da9ed7f1cee89c4a2c807243af453b96796a9e873d707c519151e53ac29e79fc in /usr/local/aws-cli/

Specifically what is this dir:sha256 sum syntax about? Docker documentation does not seem to reference this in any way.

This isn't standard Dockerfile syntax and you only see it in docker history output and places like the Docker Hub UI that present similar content.

It's copying a directory from the build cache, the long hexadecimal string is a SHA256 hash that identifies directory content in the cache.
